# Is revision control fundamentally at odds with live coding?

Tags: version-control

Both *live coding*, and *revision control*, are very valuable tools when programming. But they seem to have inherently conflicting characteristics. **Is it possible to fully benefit from both at the same time, or are they fundamentally incompatible?**

**EDIT:** To those who don't bother reading the whole length of my question: ***please*** at least **read the section *"Both together?... Existing pseudo-solutions"*** so that you won't try to sell me on non-solutions that I've already listed.

### What I mean by "revision control"

By ***revision control*** *(a.k.a. version control)* I mean mainly (quite obviously in our times) the likes of *Git, Mercurial, SVN, CVS, darcs...* etc., etc. But I like to think, that this category can be extended somewhat, to include conceptually simpler ideas, like: the now ubiquitous (however volatile) *undo/redo*; and probably also the notion of primitive *"file name versioning"* (like in: *main.c, main-old1.c, main-old2.c*), from which CVS presumably originated.

Anyway, the main premise of *revision control* is, that a programmer can store multiple *versions* of a program's source code ("snapshots" from different points in time), and quickly switch between them — "jump backwards and forwards in time". This way, one does never™ lose what he wrote.

### What I mean by "live coding"

On the other hand, ***live coding*** may sound simpler as a name, but I believe it is a label which covers a much more diverse world of concepts and solutions. Probably the most well-known of them now is the *[read-eval-print loop, or REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)*. It's present as "interactive console" in Python, Ruby, JavaScript, obviously Lisp, to name only a few. But as much as they are useful for "quick testing", in Python and the likes they are merely funny toys, when compared with systems, where REPLs were/are first-class citizens (or even the sole ones), such as IIUC: *[Smalltalk systems with their "images"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Image-based_persistence)*, to some extent *[Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language))*, some *Lisp* systems. But then, there are other variations: e.g. Erlang has *"hot swapping of modules"*. Or, there are attempts at editors like *[Light Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_Table_(software))*, experimenting with various approaches to *instant feedback*.

It's a bit harder for me to summarize what *live coding* is about, but I have to try: it's programming with *instant feedback*, when changes to a program are executed immediately, *while performing the program's main function without serious interruptions*; the programming is done in incremental way, often with much experimenting, in *tight feedback loop*, and in practice usually in volatile memory (RAM).

### Both together?... Existing pseudo-solutions

Now, both main ideas described above are very awesome, but I've **never seen them successfully combined together**. I've encountered several attempts aimed at gaining from both worlds, but they were at best half baked, and often just doubling user's work, instead of reducing it. In no particular order:

1. Matlab's command log: [image]

   - each command entered in REPL is auto-saved to a "log"/history window, from which it can be easily recalled and saved into a script file.
   - live coding: ☺ (REPL)
   - revision control: ☹ (some help via history, but then laborous manual editing and external VCS tools)
2. "Experiment in REPL, then copy successful snippets to editor"

   - live coding: ☺ (REPL)
   - revision control: ☹☹☹ (no help from computer; "what did I type to do this?"; at best rudimentary history with up/down arrows; generally "Left as an exercise for the reader")
3. "Compile and run on save"

   - live coding: ☹☹☹ (slow feedback, *whole program is restarted* and all state is lost, any inputs leading to particular state must be manually repeated on each restart)
   - revision control: ☺ (you have the code firmly on disk in some organized files, so you can easily put it in revision control; the current state of files is consistent and contains full and exact code of the program)
4. Erlang's hot-swapping of modules

   - also sometimes available (and working) in some RAD IDEs (for Java, C++)
   - live coding: ☹ (at least don't have to reset whole program and lose whole state; but much slower feedback than in REPL, very much *not* a tight feedback loop; also, usually supported only for changes not crossing boundaries of some small module; also, often requires the original program to be specially prepared in anticipation for hot-swapping of a particular module)
   - revision control: ☺ (all the benefits of normal program)

**Did you ever see a solution combining advantages of both worlds, i.e. one for which I'd be able to put a smiling face in both categories? Or, do you maybe have some strong arguments why it is logically impossible?**

(Also, in comments, I'd happily learn of other compromise solutions. I'd be also happy to learn if there is/was some method of recording history for Smalltalk systems, or at least objects in those systems?)

Comment: You get the benefits of both by creating scripts. Running scripts gives you instant feedback. You can maintain versions of scripts to keep up with changing requirements.

Comment: @RSahu: I disagree. This is the same case as "3. Compile and run on save" - especially, disadvantages include: *"whole program is restarted and all state is lost"*. Also, there are apps/systems you can't build as scripts, e.g. big servers, or GUI applications.

Comment: JRebel gives that in the context of Web Development (on save -> incremental build -> hot swap classes). So you save and in a couple of seconds your local server is already giving out modified pages (you do need to refresh the page in a browser, but you have an uninterrupted session). There are other tools that give you this, but they all rely on swapping classes out in a working JVM.

Answer (score 3):

I've never had any trouble using those two together. I just don't use those two *simultaneously*.

For example, I use [Brackets](http://brackets.io) for developing HTML/CSS templates - it does the same as REPL, but in a browser (page is getting re-rendered when user updates the code). I do it live until I'm done with some particular feature, and then do `git add`/`git commit` one or more times to fix the changes, when go back to live coding. When I'm lazy, I can just commit once after I'm done experimenting. I don't rollback my commit history while live coding - that just doesn't make any sense to me.

So, my answer is: don't use a hammer and a saw both at the same time. You can only hurt yourself that way.

Comment: What you describe matches my case "3. Compile and run on save": you say yourself that the page is *re-rendered*, i.e. "restarted". All JavaScript state (values or variables) is lost on such restart, isn't it? Also, in your case I'd be interested in solutions for JS, not HTML/CSS (these are intrinsically stateless). Also, I specifically ask if it's *possible* to use *both at the same time*, so an answer of *"don't try, because not"* doesn't bring any value for me, unfortunately.

Comment: No, the page is refreshed on the fly, no state is lost except the parts I change. It doesn't match "Compile and run on save". And it's just an example, I do the same with REPLs.

Answer (score 1):

Version control works very well with what you describe as Live coding.  Most coding I have done is more or less what you describe as Live coding, and I would call coding.

The workflow I usually use is:

- update (only needed if you are sharing code)
- commit any uncommitted changes
- code and test (you can use step-wise refinement to add full functionality)
- commit changes (try to avoid committing broken code, although committing working but incomplete changes is desirable)

Version control provides a lot of benefits. A few of the key benefits:

- You can really delete code when you don't need it now.  (You can retrieve the changes from revision control.)
- Git allows you to stash work in progress if you need to deal with a different issue.  Other tools allow you similar but more public functionality.
- You can review changes to determine where a bug was introduced.
- The risk of experimenting is significantly reduced.  You can always revert back to the code before you started the experiment.
- It is easier to maintain production and development versions of code.

For a number of reasons, you need to be able to save the code you are working on.  I have picked up the pieces from people who code and save snippets.  The problem is they kind of work, but you need to re-edit them before you can use them.   If you aren't interested in replicating your results, version control and artifacts you can version control don't matter.   Coding from a recall buffer isn't readily reusable.  Getting the code into a script that can be version controlled is key.

One thing I learned early is that there is little code that can be done as a one-off.  Live coding as you describe it seems like one-off coding.

Comment: You write "I do Live Coding", but then you describe regular non-live coding workflow ("write, compile, run"). I don't understand how this is an answer to my question. Also, I know what are benefits of version control, I don't need to be educated on that, I *did* write it provides many benefits, that's ridiculous.

Comment: @akavel See my edit. Live Coding is great for experimentation, but I haven't found a case for using it for re-usable code.